# User input String converted to double

Tags: c

The code below works, but it calculates something wrong. Please tell me what or how I should calculate it so that the output will be the same as the input. Please don't change or add new code except it's just the calculation part.

The result at the moment is just for example:

Type a String which will be converted to a double: 12.23

string 12.23 -> number 0.012

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char input[100];
    printf("Type a String which will be converted to a double: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    double number = 0.0;
    double divider = 1.0;
    double sign = 1.0;

    enum { Start, End, Error, A, B, C, D } state = Start;

    int i = 0;
    while (state != End && state != Error)
    {
        char ch = input[i];
        i++;
        switch (state)
        {
        case Start:
            if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
            {
                state = A;
                if (ch == '-')
                {
                    sign = -1.0;
                }
            }
            else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                state = B;
                number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                state = Error;
            }
            break;
        case A:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                state = B;
                number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                state = Error;
            }
            break;
        case B:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                state = B;
                number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
            }
            else if (ch == '.')
            {
                state = C;
                divider = divider * 10.0;
            }
            else if (ch == '\0')
            {
                state = End;
            }
            else
            {
                state = Error;
            }
            break;
        case C:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                state = D;
                divider = divider * 10.0;
            }
            else
            {
                state = Error;
            }
            break;
        case D:
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                state = D;
                divider = divider * 10.0;
            }
            else if (ch == '\0')
            {
                state = End;
            }
            else
            {
                state = Error;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (state == End)
    {
        printf("string %s -> number %g \n", input, sign * number / divider);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter a valid number! \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while being able to watch what happens, as well as being able to see the values of all variables. Being able to use a debugger is crucial for anyone who want to program.

Comment: hello, yes I am using the debugger, though it's my first time. I see something wrong with the divider and maybe even the number. but I don't know what's wrong, and how it should be calculated. 
I am totally confused.

Comment: Can you point out what line you are seeing might be wrong?

Comment: State `C` and `D` are calculating the divider without add the values. BTW your code, using a state machine, is, at least, weird. If is not mandatory (i guess school homework) to use state machine, think to change your implementation.

Comment: Change implementation to `strtod` unless you absolutely must write an inferior version of it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting your weird code

State `C` and `D` should be

```
case C:
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        state = D;
        divider = divider * 10.0;
        number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        state = Error;
    }
    break;
case D:
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        state = D;
        divider = divider * 10.0;
        number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
    }
    else if (ch == '\0')
    {
        state = End;
    }
    else
    {
        state = Error;
    }
    break;
```

And state `B` should avoid to increment the divider:

```
    case B:
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            state = B;
            number = number * 10.0 + ch - '0';
        }
        else if (ch == '.')
        {
            state = C;
        }
        else if (ch == '\0')
        {
            state = End;
        }
        else
        {
            state = Error;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. 
To answer your comment below my state:
The start of the code was already given to me and they told me I had to do it with the states for exercise. Then they said the structure is okay, but the calculation was wrong and I didn't find out what exactly was wrong. Now I got it, thank you. Usually I would have tried it on another way.